# Azure Stream Analytics: REST Api for creating new ASA job giving MissingApiVersionParameter error

Tags: api, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I want to create new ASA job using rest end point with input output and query for job.
I've followed this link

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-job

and formed below url according to above link

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/
>   resourcegroups/{resourcegroup-name}/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/
>   streamingjobs/dynamicStream?api-version=2015-10-01

Though I've provided api version query parameter, postman is giving me below error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "MissingApiVersionParameter",
        "message": "The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests."
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?
Api for creating new input for stream analytics job is behaving in same way

Thank you for reading !!!

Comment: Are you properly encoding your request url? I had problems with webservice params in the past because i didnt properly encode the request url.

Comment: I'm trying from postman, so there isn't anything like encoding of url..
Thanks a lot Fabian !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSTMAN issue !
Tried using different method and it's working .